# Getting each individual digit from a whole integer

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

Let's say I have an integer called 'score', that looks like this:

```
int score = 1529587;
```

Now what I want to do is get each digit 1, 5, 2, 9, 5, 8, 7 from the score <strike>using bitwise operators</strike>(See below edit note).

I'm pretty sure this can be done since I've once used a similar method to extract the red green and blue values from a hexadecimal colour value.

How would I do this?

**Edit**
It doesn't necessarily have to be bitwise operators, I just thought it'd be simpler that way.

Comment: Since I did not find it in my personal bit operator compendium (http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html), I do not think that this is possible without some deeper elaboration.

Comment: if they are decimal you can't get them using bitwise. if they are hexadecimal then it is possible. please specify.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You use the modulo operator:

```
while(score)
{
    printf("%d\n", score % 10);
    score /= 10;
}
```

Note that this will give you the digits in reverse order (i.e. least significant digit first). If you want the most significant digit first, you'll have to store the digits in an array, then read them out in reverse order.

Comment: I'm pretty sure modulo is not a bitwise operator

Comment: @Scorpi0: No, it isn't... but there's no sensible way to do this using bitwise operators, and I think this is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: i think what OP meant hexadecimal and it is possible to solve with bitwise.

Comment: @Andrey from the example it's clear OP is asking about decimal digits.

Comment: This solution assumes score >= 0. If `score<0` then this function will never terminate.

Comment: @Kuai   Loop [will terminate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer#comment57974275_3118505) if `score` originally less than 0.  This answer unfortunately prints nothing with `score==0`.

Comment: A do while loop would fix that

Answer (score 5):

RGB values fall nicely on bit boundaries; decimal digits don't. I don't think there's an easy way to do this using bitwise operators at all. You'd need to use decimal operators like modulo 10 (% 10).

Comment: +1 He's right, decimal (base 10) numbers do not partition on bits (base 2), except for numbers that are powers of 2 (like 256 = 2^8 for colors). Since 10 is not a power of 2, you will not be able to use bitwise operators.

Answer (score 4):

Agree with previous answers.

A little correction: There's a better way to print the decimal digits from left to right, without allocating extra buffer. In addition you may want to display a zero characeter if the `score` is 0 (the loop suggested in the previous answers won't print anythng).

This demands an additional pass:

```
int div;
for (div = 1; div <= score; div *= 10)
    ;

do
{
    div /= 10;
    printf("%d\n", score / div);
    score %= div;
} while (score);
```

Comment: This solution causes a divide by zero when `score` is zero.

Comment: This solution also fails due to overflow when score >= ceil (INT_MAX / 10.0).  I've provided a solution which works correction for the entire range [0, UINT_MAX].

Comment: This solution also fails for any number with 0 digits in the least significant position or positions.  Those zeros aren't printed.  The corrected solution I've provided avoids this problem also.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel. C has `sprintf` for a reason.

Since your variable is called score, I'm guessing this is for a game where you're planning to use the individual digits of the score to display the numeral glyphs as images. In this case, `sprintf` has convenient format modifiers that will let you zero-pad, space-pad, etc. the score to a fixed width, which you may want to use.

Comment: I like how you analyzed EXACTLY what I was going to use it for Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This solution gives correct results over the entire range [0,UINT_MAX]
without requiring digits to be buffered.

It also works for wider types or signed types (with positive values) with appropriate type changes.

This kind of approach is particularly useful on tiny environments (e.g. Arduino bootloader) because it doesn't end up pulling in all the printf() bloat (when printf() isn't used for demo output) and uses very little RAM.  You can get a look at value just by blinking a single led :)

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  unsigned int score = 42;   // Works for score in [0, UINT_MAX]

  printf ("score via printf:     %u\n", score);   // For validation

  printf ("score digit by digit: ");
  unsigned int div = 1;
  unsigned int digit_count = 1;
  while ( div <= score / 10 ) {
    digit_count++;
    div *= 10;
  }
  while ( digit_count > 0 ) {
    printf ("%d", score / div);
    score %= div;
    div /= 10;
    digit_count--;
  }
  printf ("\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//this can be easily understandable for beginners     
int score=12344534;
int div;
for (div = 1; div <= score; div *= 10)
{

}
/*for (div = 1; div <= score; div *= 10); for loop with semicolon or empty body is same*/
while(div>1)
{
    div /= 10;
    printf("%d\n`enter code here`", score / div);
    score %= div;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't handle zero's at the end, for example 12344540 would not print last 0 digit

Comment: quick fix is to use conditional like while(score || div >1) or just while(div >1)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this problem resolve with using the modulo of a number in a loop or convert a number to a string. For convert a number to a string, you may can use the function [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), so considering the variant with the modulo of a number in a loop.

---

Content of a file `get_digits.c`

```
$ cat get_digits.c 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


// return a length of integer
unsigned long int get_number_count_digits(long int number);

// get digits from an integer number into an array
int number_get_digits(long int number, int **digits, unsigned int *len);

// for demo features
void demo_number_get_digits(long int number);


int
main()
{
    demo_number_get_digits(-9999999999999);
    demo_number_get_digits(-10000000000);
    demo_number_get_digits(-1000);
    demo_number_get_digits(-9);
    demo_number_get_digits(0);
    demo_number_get_digits(9);
    demo_number_get_digits(1000);
    demo_number_get_digits(10000000000);
    demo_number_get_digits(9999999999999);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


unsigned long int
get_number_count_digits(long int number)
{
    if (number < 0)
        number = llabs(number);
    else if (number == 0)
        return 1;

    if (number < 999999999999997)
        return floor(log10(number)) + 1;

    unsigned long int count = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        ++count;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return count;
}


int
number_get_digits(long int number, int **digits, unsigned int *len)
{
    number = labs(number);

    // termination count digits and size of a array as well as
    *len = get_number_count_digits(number);

    *digits = realloc(*digits, *len * sizeof(int));

    // fill up the array
    unsigned int index = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        (*digits)[index] = (int)(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
        ++index;
    }

    // reverse the array
    unsigned long int i = 0, half_len = (*len / 2);
    int swap;
    while (i < half_len) {
        swap = (*digits)[i];
        (*digits)[i] = (*digits)[*len - i - 1];
        (*digits)[*len - i - 1] = swap;
         ++i;
    }

    return 0;
}


void
demo_number_get_digits(long int number)
{
    int *digits;
    unsigned int len;

    digits = malloc(sizeof(int));

    number_get_digits(number, &digits, &len);

    printf("%ld --> [", number);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i == len - 1)
            printf("%d", digits[i]);
        else
            printf("%d, ", digits[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");

    free(digits);
}
```

---

Demo with the GNU GCC

```
$~/Downloads/temp$ cc -Wall -Wextra -std=c11 -o run get_digits.c -lm
$~/Downloads/temp$ ./run
-9999999999999 --> [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
-10000000000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
-1000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0]
-9 --> [9]
0 --> [0]
9 --> [9]
1000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0]
10000000000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9999999999999 --> [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Demo with the LLVM/Clang

```
$~/Downloads/temp$ rm run
$~/Downloads/temp$ clang -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra get_digits.c -o run -lm
setivolkylany$~/Downloads/temp$ ./run
-9999999999999 --> [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
-10000000000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
-1000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0]
-9 --> [9]
0 --> [0]
9 --> [9]
1000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0]
10000000000 --> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
9999999999999 --> [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

---

**Testing environment**

```
$~/Downloads/temp$ cc --version | head -n 1
cc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
$~/Downloads/temp$ clang --version
Debian clang version 3.5.0-10 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: `itoa` is nonstandard, and AFAIK is not implemented on any major platform.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
int num; //given integer
int reminder;
int rev=0; //To reverse the given integer
int count=1;

printf("Enter the integer:");
scanf("%i",&num);

/*First while loop will reverse the number*/
while(num!=0)
{
    reminder=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+reminder;
    num/=10;
}
/*Second while loop will give the number from left to right*/
while(rev!=0)
{
    reminder=rev%10;
    printf("The %d digit is %d\n",count, reminder);
    rev/=10;
    count++; //to give the number from left to right 
}
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);}
```

Comment: here is a modified version of that that will pad with zero

`uint64_t num = 5;
uint64_t limit = 4;
char * what[limit+1];
what[limit+1] = '\0';
uint64_t remainder = 0;
uint64_t rev = 0;
int count = 1;
int digits = 0;
while(num!=0) {
    remainder=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+remainder;
    num/=10;
    digits++;
}
if (remainder == 1 && digits != remainder) digits--;
if (digits < limit)
    while(digits!=limit) {
        rev=rev*10;
        digits++;
    }
while(rev!=0) {
    remainder=rev%10;
    what[count] = "0123456789"[remainder];
    rev/=10;
    count++;
}`

Comment: in which if num is `5` and limit is `4` then it will produce `0005`

Answer (score 0):

First convert your integer to a string using `sprintf`, then do whatever you want with its elements, that are `chars`. Assuming an `unsigned` score:

```
unsigned int score = 1529587, i;
char stringScore [11] = { 0 };

sprintf( stringScore, "%d, score );

for( i=0; i<strlen(stringScore); i++ )
    printf( "%c\n", stringScore[i] );
```

Please note how:

- It prints digits starting from the most significant one
- `stringScore` is 11 characters long assuming that the size of `int`, in your platform, is 4 bytes, so that the maximum integer is 10 digits long. The eleventh one is for the string terminator character `'\0'`.
- `sprintf` makes all the work for you

---

### Do you need to have an integer for every single digit?

Since we are sure that `stringScore` contains only digits, the conversion is really easy. If `dig` is the character containing the digit, the corresponding integer can be obtained in this way:

```
int intDigit = dig - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, event though it's been answered, I figure I'll stick my nose in it...

We're going to extract numbers from least to most significant, i.e. visibly in reverse order.

We are actually extracting the position, or index, within a radix palette. A radix, or base, is a basis for a numeral system. Base-10 simply means 10 digits, base-2 means 2 digits, etc.

If we use base 16 instead, as an example, we end up with positions that reach beyond our familiar 10 "digits" (i.e. 10 through 15, which are later translated to the letters A through F). Anyways...

```
int value = 564738291;
int radix = 10;
int array[32]; // At the end = { 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1 }
int index = 0; // At the end = 9

if(value == 0) // If value is zero ..
{
    array[index++] = 0; // .. we add a zero, and we're done.
}
else
{
    while(value != 0)
    {
        array[index++] = value % radix; // Copy the value into the array.
        value /= radix;
    }
}
```

At the end here, our array will have been filled with numbers, that for base-10 and below, can be directly used as digits, but for any radix above 10, the numbers will have to be translated to whatever "characters" will be used to visualize the numbers of the chosen radix.

E.g. in hexadecimal the numbers can be: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15. When printed they can be translate, respectively, to '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'. So the numbers in the array are still correct, but they are really just indices within the chosen radix.

The point though is that this can be used to extract the value in radix = 2 (binary, you get ones and zeroes), or any other base for that matter.

You can use it with base-20 (vigesimal) and then translate those possible 20 numbers to the Mayan numerals (or any other system that also uses base-20) in Unicode, or why not do the Babylonian base-60. :)

Also, the larger the radix, the less "digits" needed to represent a number. This is why the smallest radix, base-2 (just ones and zeroes) are always so long, 32 for an int (see the size of the array in the pseudo-code above).

The resulting numbers in the array can also be used to reference things like images or fabricated drawing functions, etc., instead of Unicode.

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

Answer (score -1):

I've made this solution, it-s simple instead read an integer, i read a string (char array in C), then write with a for bucle, the code also write the sum of digits

```
// #include<string.h>

scanf("%s", n);
int total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i< strlen(n); i++){
    printf("%c", n[i]);
    total += (int)(n[i]) -48;
}

printf("%d", total);
```