# How can I iterate through each digit in a 3 digit number in C?

Tags: c

Length is always 3, examples:

```
000
056
999
```

How can I get the number so I can use the value of the single digit in an array?

Would it be easier to convert to an `char`, loop through it and convert back to `int` when needed?

Comment: Similar questions have been asked many times and a simple google search turns up plenty of good answers.

Comment: duplicate of: [Getting each individual digit from a whole integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer)

Comment: What form are these numbers have when you get them?  Values of type `int`?  Character strings?

Answer (score 6):

To get the decimal digit at position `p` of an integer `i` you would do this:

```
(i / pow(p, 10)) % 10;
```

So to loop from the last digit to the first digit, you would do this:

```
int n = 56; // 056
int digit;    

while(n) {
    digit = n % 10;
    n /= 10;

    // Do something with digit
}
```

Easy to modify to do it exactly 3 times.

Answer (score -3):

As Austin says, you can easily find answers on Google. But it basically involves mod-by-10, then divide-by-ten. Assuming integers.