# How to count total appearance of 0 or 1 from range number 1 to n?

Tags: c, algorithm, numbers

So, I want to find how many digit 0 or 1 appear in a range of number. For example:
I want to find how many 0 appear from number 1 to 100. The answer is, 0 appear 11 times. I want to implement it to C, but I don't know how to do it.

So, the first thing I want is to receive an input type int(assume the int is n). Then, from number 1 to n, how many 0 appear in those range, and how many 1 appear in those range. Then print the total of how many 0 appear and how many 1 appear.

This is what I've tried, but not complete yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N, totalZero = 0;

    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (int i=N; i>0; i--)
    {
        //statement
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what I must do int the //statement inside the for.

Comment: this looks like part of an assignment (be it homework, or a book, or a tutorial doesn't matter). Surely you were given all the pieces required to solve this task. Look back on your materials and find where they explain how to decompose a number into digits.

Comment: I'd argue that the question is not a duplicate. It can be done in O(log N) time without having to iterate and getting each individual digit from a whole number. However, it does appear to be part of an assignment.

Comment: Iterating over all numbers in the range is not the best solution to this problem.

Comment: @rici I have no idea to solve it efficienly. Could you please give me your apporach?

Comment: Your problem is not unambiguously specified; in the range 1 to 100, the _number_ zero does not occur at all and in any range any value can occor only zero or one time.  Presumably you mean _digits_ 0 or 1, not _numbers_.

Comment: @Clifford yeah I'm sorry, I mean how many digit. Thanks for your correction!

Comment: @BernardJosephus: Do it digit position by digit position, and split the ranges into pieces which make that count easier.

Comment: @rici sorry, but I don't get what you mean. Can you provide your solution by code?

Comment: @bernhard: how many 1s are there in the numbers between 1 and 999999999? I'll bet you can figure it out without a computer in a few minutes. Count each digit position separately. How many ones in the last position? How many in the second last? Etc.

Comment: Trying to provide more information as to why this question is not a duplicate.
Finding the number of digits counting from 1 to N is not the same as finding individual digits of a whole number. Perhaps, moderators/reviewers thought of the most naive solution to iterate over each number and finding individual digits which is not the same. This is an algorithm question and could be solved without finding individual digits of each number. Instead, we could solve this mathematically as illustrated: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jKzVxrDKzS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved mathematically without iterating over each number in the range and counting its digits.
It works by calculating the number of times a specific digit appears at each place.

## Example

Let us take an example of counting the number of 7s from `1` to `3876`.

The number of times 7 occurs at each place

- 1s place: `(0)7, 17, 27, ..., 107,...3867` = `387` x `1` times
- 10s place:
  `(0)70, 71, 72, 73,..., 79, 170,..., 179,...3770, ..., 3779` = `38` x
  `10` = 380 and between 3870, ..., 3876: 7 times which equals `387`.
- 100s place: `700, ... 799, ..., 3700, ... 3799` = `(3 + 1)` x `100` = `400`
- 1000s place: `0` times.

Total = `387` + `387` + `400` = `1174` which is the desired result.

## Code

We define `cntdigit(N, digit)` as a function which returns the number of times a `digit` appears if counted from `1` to `N`.

```
long long cntdigit(long long n, int digit)
{
  long long j;
  long long res = 0;
  for(j = 1; n/j; j *= 10) {
    long long curdigit = (n / j) % 10;
    res += (n / j / 10) * j;
    if (curdigit > digit)
      res += j;
    else if (curdigit == digit)
      res += n % j + 1;

    if (digit == 0)
      res -= j;
  }
  return res;
}
```

## Time complexity:

The problem can be solved for any arbitrary digit in `O(d)` time complexity where `d` is the number of digits base `10` for `n`.

## Explanation:

1. Iterate over all digits of the number `n` by dividing it with exponents of `10` and mod `10` to get each digit. (Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer) for more details).
2. We then begin to count at each place, the number of times `digit` occurs.
3. At each place, the left part (which is the quotient when divided by 10's exponent) is the number of times a digit occurs in the ones place, tens place, hundredth's place and so on.
4. If the current digit is greater than the `digit` then we add `j` (10s exponent) to account for counting for all quotients starting from 0.
5. If the current digit is equal to the `digit` then the number of times that digit occurs in that place is the remainder for the exponent + 1.
6. Lastly, if the digit to be counted is `0`, then we need to subtract the number of times the quotient was `0`. **Why?** Because we don't want to count 0s for numbers starting with leading 0s. For example, you wouldn't want to count 0 in numbers, 01, 02, 03 and so on.

The solution can be easily extended to count between ranges `a` to `b` by subtracting the solution for `b` and `a - 1`:

```
int main()
{
  long long a, b;
  // Range and digit
  scanf("%lld %lld", &a, &b, &digit);
  printf("%lld ", cntdigit(b, i) - cntdigit(a-1, i));
  return 0;
}
```

If you're interested, you could test your solution for a general case of this problem at [SPOJ](https://www.spoj.com/problems/MDIGITS/)

Comment: Thanks so much, it's faster now. But, I am still trying to fully understand your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the result each time the remainder of `i / 10` = `0` or `1`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int max = 100;
    int n0 = 0;
    int n1 = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        for (int x = i; x != 0; x /= 10) {
            switch (x % 10) {
                case 0: n0++; break;
                case 1: n1++; break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("0 appears %d times\n", n0);
    printf("1 appears %d times\n", n1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: & what about number of 1's ? this only print occurence of 0's only

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning that the solution is not optimal and it can be done using trivial mathematics in O(log N) time without iterating each number in the range.

Comment: @Keine Lust Thanks, It solved my problem. But, I don't understand why you use void inside the main method.

Comment: @BernhardJosephus `void` means with no parameters, empty means undefined number of parameters, `int main()` is not a valid prototype for `main`.

Comment: @KeineLust I still don't get what the significance difference between int main(void) and int main(). And which one is better to use?

Comment: @BernhardJosephus use `int main(void)`

Answer (score 0):

As your question:
E.g.: 1..100. The "Zero" number will appear 11 times. That means: 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 and 100(11 times that the zero number appear)

So what is condition inside the for loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void count(int &n)
{
    printf("Input n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int value=0;
    int value2=0;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        int x = i;
        while (x>0)
        {
            if(x==100 && x%10==0)
            {
                x/=10;
                if(x==10)
                    value+=2;
            }
            else if(x%10==0)
                value++;
            else if(x%10==1) 
                value2++;
            x/=10;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d",value);
    printf("\n%d",value2);
}

int main()

{
    int n;
    count(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "That means: 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 and 100(11 times that the zero number appear)" Well, I see 12 zeros... In other words: Your code doesn't work as it only finds trailing zero

Comment: are you sure this code is correct ? this will check the remainder from 0 to 100 & count is just 1 here. you can write nested loop here & on each iteration from 0 to 100 check each digit of a number either it is 0 or not.

Comment: The requirement of the problem only counts the number of occurrences of the number 0. It does not require counting the number of zeroes appear how many times in a certain number eg 100 (0 counts are counted as one time, not two times). This is a basic math problem, we do not need to complicate it

Comment: For 100 it is two zeros. Notice how OP use the range *1* to 100 and gets the result 11. OP does **not** start from 0

Comment: The solution still not correct after I test it. Your solution just divide number by 10. So, when I enter 100, the answer is 10 instead of 11