# C Language - add products’ digits (i.e., not the products themselves)

Tags: c

I am looking to calculate the below sum but using the products digits, not the products themselves:

These are the initial values:

2 + 12 + 8 = 22

but what I want to achieve is the following, so that the digit 12 is actually seen as a 1 and a 2 separately

2 + 1 + 2 + 8 = 13

Using C language is there a formula in which I can use to perform this task?

Comment: No, there is no standard C functions for doing that. However, it's easy to write some code doing that. In a loop you use `digit = n % 10` to get a digit and `n = n / 10` to prepare for getting the next digit.

Comment: where the values come from ? do you have them in an array for instance ? or do you have their external representation (string rather than int) ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer

Comment: Do you ever have any other operator between the numbers other than `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have an array of the values you can do :

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned sum(const unsigned * a, size_t sz)
{
  unsigned sum = 0;

  while (sz--) {
    unsigned v = *a++;

    while (v) {
      sum += v%10;
      v /= 10;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

int main()
{
  const unsigned a[] = { 2, 12, 8 };

  printf("sum = %u\n", sum(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)));
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -pedantic -Wextra s.c
/tmp % ./a.out
sum = 13
```

Answer (score 1):

If `+` is the only other token, then you can disregard it and merely sum the digits on the stream. So

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // for isdigit

int main(void)
{
    char* s = "2 + 12 + 8";
    int total = 0;
    for (; *s; ++s){
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)*s)){
            total += *s - '0';
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```

is one way. `*s - '0';` is the idiomatic way of transforming a `char` digit to its numerical value. The loop termination condition is the NUL terminator in the string `s`.

This is most certainly not the best approach if you want other operators between terms. At that point you need to build a full expression parser (such as one based on the worked example in Kernighan & Ritchie).

Comment: To avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values on systems that have signed `char` by default, you should write `isdigit((unsigned char)*s)`. I might be more readable to write `(*s >= '0' && *s <= '9')`

Comment: @chqrlie: I can still here my professor shouting at me for this all those years ago. Fixed.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct formula for this task but you can perform this task in a separate **function** and use that function wherever it is needed.
Here are two simple solutions which depend on the type of input.

If **Input** is in the form of **String** (i.e. "2 + 12 + 8") then the code will be -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "2 + 12 + 8";
    int sum=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
            sum += str[i] - '0';
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

If **Input** is in the form of **Array** (i.e. [2, 12, 8]) then the code will be -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num[] = {2, 12, 8};
    int sum=0;
    int length = sizeof(num) / sizeof(num[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        while (num[i]) {
            sum += num[i] % 10;
            num[i] /= 10; 
        }
    }
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```