# how do i check if a number has only unique digits?

Tags: c

for example, 2345 is a unique digit number because no digit is shown twice but 3324 isn't a unique number because 3 is there twice. I tried using % but I as (code) shows but I didn't get digits I got numbers, edit: you cant use strings

```
number%10==number%100||number%10==number%1000||number%100==number%1000
```

Comment: Hints, define an array `int visited[10] = {0}`. Then populate this by extracting the rightmost digit using `% 10` and removing that digit using `/ 10`. The treatment of superfluous leading zeros might need some thought.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer does this help?

Comment: hmmm... 11 in binary is represented as `1011`, in hexadecimal as `b`

Answer (score 6):

You could use an array of 10 flags to indicate whether a digit has been seen yet. Work your way through the number in a loop, extracting the units digit, checking whether the digit has been seen, flagging the digit as seen, and dividing the number by 10 for the next iteration.

As pointed out by @Bathsheba, some care is needed when dealing with negative
numbers.

For example:

```
int unique(long long int number)
{
    char seen[10] = {0};

    while (number) {
        int digit = number % 10;

        number /= 10;
        if (digit < 0) {
            /* 
             * The number was negative.  Make it positive.
             * (Note: Checking the number is negative before the while
             * loop could fail when number is LLONG_MIN, so do it here
             * instead.)
             */
            digit = -digit;
            number = -number;
        }
        if (seen[digit]++)
            return 0; /* not unique */
     }
     return 1; /* unique */
 }
```

Separate functions may be needed if it is necessary to deal with both `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`, but the one that handles `long long int` can make use of the one that handles `unsigned long long int` as follows:

```
#include <limits.h>

int unique_ull(unsigned long long int number)
{
    char seen[10] = {0};

    while (number) {
        int digit = number % 10;

        number /= 10;
        if (seen[digit]++)
            return 0; /* not unique */
     }
     return 1; /* unique */
 }

int unique_ll(long long int number)
{
    unsigned long long int n;

    /* Represent original number as a 2's complement number. */
    n = number;
    if (n > LLONG_MAX) {
        /*
         * Original number was negative, so take its 2's complement to "negate" it.
         * (Note: This works even when original number is LLONG_MIN.)
         */
        n = -n;
    }
    /* Handle as an unsigned long long int. */
    return unique_ull(n);
 }
```

I suppose it would be useful to support `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` in the same way:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int unique_um(uintmax_t number)
{
    char seen[10] = {0};

    while (number) {
        int digit = number % 10;

        number /= 10;
        if (seen[digit]++)
            return 0; /* not unique */
     }
     return 1; /* unique */
 }

int unique_m(intmax_t number)
{
    uintmax_t n;

    /* Represent original number as a 2's complement number. */
    n = number;
    if (n > INTMAX_MAX) {
        /*
         * Original number was negative, so take its 2's complement to "negate" it.
         * (Note: This works even when original number is INTMAX_MIN.)
         */
        n = -n;
    }
    /* Handle as a uintmax_t. */
    return unique_um(n);
 }
```

Comment: Needs thought if `number` is negative. (Personally I'd change the type to `unsigned long long`.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, I added a safe correction for negative numbers. I guess it needs a different function for `unsigned long long` in case someone actually does need to use it with negative `long long` numbers.

Answer (score 1):

My five cents.:)

For starters the parameter of the function should have the type `long long int` (or `intmax_t`). In this case the function can be applied to objects of any signed integer type.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int unique_digits( long long int n )
{
    const long long int Base = 10;

    int unique = 1;

    while ( unique && n )
    {
        long long int digit = n % Base;
        long long int tmp = n /= Base;

        while (tmp && digit != tmp % Base ) tmp /= Base;

        unique = tmp == 0;
    }

    return unique;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n = 12345678;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = 12345671;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = -12345678;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = -112345671;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
12345678: unique
12345671: non_unique
-12345678: unique
-112345671: non_unique
```

If to include the header `<stdint.h>` then the type `long long int` can be substituted for the type `intmax_t`.

Another approach is to use an integer as an array of digits. Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int unique_digits( long long int n )
{
    const long long int Base = 10;

    unsigned short unique = 0;

    long long int digit;
    int offset;

    do
    {
        digit = n % Base;
        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;

        offset = 1 << digit;
        unique ^= offset;
    } while ( ( unique & offset ) && ( n /= Base )  );        

    return n == 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int n = 12345678;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = 12345671;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = -12345678;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    n = -112345671;

    printf( "%d: %s\n", n, unique_digits( n ) ? "unique" : "non_unique" );

    return 0;
}
```

It output is the same as of the previous program

```
12345678: unique
12345671: non_unique
-12345678: unique
-112345671: non_unique
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set STL in order to check if a number has only unique digits. For example, let us consider number 2020, then we can convert the number into the string,

```
int num;
cin>>num
string s = to_string(num);
```

After that, initialise a set with the contents of **string s**.

```
set<int> uniDigits(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Then we can compare the size of **string s** and newly created set **uniDigits**.

```
if(s.size() == uniDigits.size()) { break; }
```

As we know the property of sets, that **set stores only unique numbers** and discards repeated digits, then if both sizes are equal that means all digits are unique. If size of set is less than that of the string, that means the number does not contain distinct digits and all the repeated numbers are discarded.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "2020";
    set<int> digits(s.begin(), s.end());
    cout << s.size() << " " << digits.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the size of string is 4 and size of set is 2, because the string contains two repeated digits.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one approach to achieve this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n, i, digit;
    static int arr[10];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n>0){
        digit = n%10;
        arr[digit]++;
        n=n/10;
    }
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        if(arr[i]>1){
            printf("Not unique!");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i==10){
        printf("unique");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the elements of static array is initialized with the default value of 0.