# Has number unique digits?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to solve a problem set on codeforce where I need to check if an positive integer number has unique digits. My solutions includes a while loop and two for loops, which is quite a lot of for such an easy task.

I found a more elegant [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577683/how-do-i-check-if-a-number-has-only-unique-digits) but I don't fully understand how the code works. I have commented it with my remarks. Could someone explain to me  the second 2) and fifth 5) part?

```
int unique(long long int number){
    
    /* 1) create array/list with 10 elements, the first element seen[0]
     * is equal to zero  */
    char seen[10] = {0};  
       
    /* 2) what is the meaning of while(some random integer number)? I thought
     * that the argument must be a statement that is either true or false. */    
    while (number) {
              
        int digit = number % 10; // 3) get the last digit of the number
    
        number /= 10;  // 4) removes last digit of the number

        /* 5) Could someone explain to me what seen[digit]++ does. And when its
         * true or false? */
              
        if (seen[digit]++) 
            return 0; /* not unique */
     }
     return 1; /* unique */
 }
```

Of course I tried to figure out the fifth part on my own but

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char seen[10] = {0};
    cout << seen[7]++ << endl;
}
```

print outs nothing.

Comment: You are asking basic C++ questions which could be answered by any good C++ book.  You can't learn C++ by answering questions from an online "judge" website -- those sites assume you know the language you're using well enough to not need to ask basic questions concerning the language.

Comment: You are right, i should invest time to properly learn the basics. I thought that i could learn C++ by just simply answer easy questions on this site, since i have experience in python.

Comment: C++ and python are two different languages.  It is like trying to learn French, and using Russian as a guide in learning French.  Do not use other computer languages as a model in learning or understanding C++.  You will get confused, or worse, create programs that are buggy, inefficient, or just look plain weird to a C++ programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go by parts:

2 ) The implicit conversion between a numeric type and bool returns **false** if the number is zero and true otherwise. You  could read `while(number)` like `while(number != 0)`

5 ) This works the same way: `seen[digit]++` is an expression with the same value as `seen[digit]` but that then increments its value (check how post-increment works). Therefore, the first time that `digit` is seen, `seen[digit]++` has the value  `0` (*so the first time the condition is not met*) and increments its value to `1` (*so the second time the condition will be met, making the function return*).

Comment: Re: "The implicit cast" -- there is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. The term you're looking for is "implicit conversion". +1.

Comment: Also, as to terminology, `seen[digit]` is an expression, and it **has a value**. It is not a function, and it doesn't **return** anything. So the first time that `digit` is seen, the **value** of `seen[digit]++` is 0.

Answer (score 0):

`while(number)` means the cycle will repeat until number is not zero. Non-zero number is equal to `true`

`seen[digit]++`  does following:

1. it return current value of seen[digit]. For the first time it will be zero - as no number met.
2. after returning current value - it increase value by one. So for the first call it will return 0 and the seen[digit] will become 1.

So for the second call it will return 1 - that mean this number already met, so it is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Q.1 `what is the meaning of while(some random integer number)? I thought that the argument must be a statement that is either true or false.`

=> Yes you are right while condition checks for true and false. In case of integer, 0 is treated as false and rest of the integers as true. So, whenever number become 0, while loop will break.

Q.2 `Could someone explain to me what seen[digit]++ does. And when its true or false?`

=>  `seen` is declared as an array of size 10 and initialized all entries as 0. So initially every entry of array `seen` is zero i.e. seen[0] = 0, seen[1] = 0, seen[2] = 1... seen[9] = 0. Now when we find `digit` and perform `seen[digit]++` it will increase value by 1 every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so:

1. Every number not equal to 0 is true and equal to 0 is false. For example 1 2 and 3 are true, but 0 is false. So `while (number)` will iterate as long as `number != 0`
2. `seen[digit]++` first returns the value, then increments itself by one after returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ `0` evaluates to `false` and any other number evaluates to `true`. That "random number" is actually modified inside the loop with `number /= 10`. Division of integer numbers in C++ is special in the sense that it does not yield fractions so `51/10 = 5` and `5/10 = 0`. At some point `number` equals 0 and the loop ends.

`seen[digit]++` is a commonly used trick. You lookup the table `seen` at position `digit` return the current value and increment the value by 1. So if you would modify your example code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int seen[10] = {0};
    cout << seen[7]++ << endl;
    cout << seen[7] << endl;
}
```

Your console output should be:

```
0
1
```

There is also `++seen[digit]` which would first increment and then return the value so you would get:

```
1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if(number)` is same as `if(number != 0)`.

- **Point 2**: After we have processed the last digit in the number, the value of `number/10` will be 0 (as the last digit belongs to 0-9) and there we end our loop.
- **Point 5**: The increment number will increment the value in the array and return the old value. If the value is incremented to 2, then it means that the digit is not unique and increment operation returns us `1` and the if condition is satisfied.