# Modulo in order to get single int from long

Tags: c, for-loop, long-integer

C language question. 
My task is to get second to the last, third to the last digit etc. from a long. 
Got a hint to do it by using modulo operator:

```
int main(void)
{
    a = get_long("n:\n");

    mod = a % 10;

    printf("%i", mod);
}
```

Works great for the rightmost digit but I just can't figure it out how to get second-, third-to the last digit, and so on.
I am trying to put the function into a for loop but it does not work at all. 
Do you have any ideas how to accopmlish that?

I am not looking for a ready solution - just for the path to follow.

Comment: a % 10, a / 10, a % 10, a / 10...

Comment: seems like a dupe of [Getting each individual digit from a whole integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer) or others that can be found by searching

Comment: This seems like processing a card number. Input a string, instead of an integer. The digit characters are all laid out for you. Always use strings for card and phone numbers.

Comment: Notice that `1234 / 10 == 123`. The rest should be easy.

Comment: "I am trying to put the function into a for loop but it does not work at all." No need to hide your attempts.

Answer (score 2):

You started off right, the first iteration will give you the rightmost digit. After that, you need to reduce the original number in a way such that the one but last number becomes the last one.

Solution: Divide by 10. Every time you divide the number by 10 (integer division), the rightmost digit *disappears* and the last but one digit becomes the last digit. So, you can keep using the same login with modulo to obtain the new last digit.

Something like

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = get_long("n:\n"); //why no datatype?

    int mod = -1;

    for (; a > 0; a/=10){  // check if a> 0, perform the modulo, and then divide by 10
        mod = a % 10;
        printf("%i\n", mod);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I see it working but please explain to me How is it working? Why 'mod' has to be -1 at the beginning?

Comment: @piotrektnw It's the same step, repeated multiple times. Use a pen and paper and do the calculation, or run the program through a debugger, it'll be easier to understand. and regarding the `-1`, it's just a value used for initialization, no specific significance.