# Program to determine weather an integer is undulating

Tags: c

Im having trouble writing this program. It is supposed to read an integer entered by a user and determine if the number is undulating or not. An undulating number being a number of any length that has the form ABABAB. Examples of undulating numbers include:
101 121 131 141 202 383 4747

Here is the code I have now, But it only works about half of the time, and I'm not sure what else to do. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
    // TODO: your code here
    int Number, FirstDigit, Count, LastDigit;
    print("Enter a number");
    scanf("%d", & Number);
    if (Number== 0){
        printf("%d is not an undulating number", Number);
    }
    else{
    
    
    Count = log10(Number);
    
    FirstDigit = Number / pow(10, Count);
  
    printf("%d", FirstDigit);
    }
    LastDigit = Number % 10;
    
    if (LastDigit == FirstDigit){
        printf("%d is an undulating number",Number);
    }
    else {
        printf("%d is not an undulating number",Number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please define "undulating". Examples alone do not adequately describe that term. And how does it relate to the question title which references "even" rather than "undulating" integers?

Comment: @kaylum I just added a further definition, let me know if that helps.

Comment: As for any program which is dealing with digits without any numerical meaning to them - I suggest to work with the numbers as strings. You will have the digits for free then.

Comment: You need to first work out the algorithm. Write the steps down on paper. Clearly your current code isn't really making much of an attempt. All it is doing is checking the first and last digits. A simple brute force approach would be to repeatedly check with increasing prefix lengths. That is, get the first digit and check if every other digit is the same. If yes then it is undulating. Otherwise get the first two digits and then check if the remaining digits repeat that pattern. And so on.

Comment: @kaylum I see what you mean. Of course, I have figured out how to determine the first digit, but how would you go about determining what the value of every other digit is?

Comment: As @EugeneSh. has mentioned it is easier to work with strings/characters in this case. If you do want to continue to use numbers then do a search. There are plenty of posts that show how to extract each digit. For example: [Getting each individual digit from a whole integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer)

Comment: I think a property is that  number is undulating in either the forward or reverse direction. So, you can start from the left (i.e. most significant digit) and look for ABABAB. Or, you can start from the right (i.e. least significant digit) and look for BABABA. From the right, it is easy to get the digit. After some initial setup of (e.g.) `int BA[2] = { -1, -1 };`, you can loop on: `int odd = 0, nomatch = 1; for (;  num != 0;  num /= 10, odd = ! odd) { int curdig = num / 10; if (BA[odd] < 0) BA[odd] = curdig; nomatch = (curdig != BA[odd]); if (nomatch) break; }`

Comment: Is a single digit number (e.g. `1-9`) undulating? If _not_, you'll need to count the number of digits you scan to ensure that it's at least 2. If a single digit number that is _not_ 0 _is_ undulating, you can just ensure the count is at least 1. This handles a number that is 0 _without_ special casing it.

Comment: Correction: It should be: `int curdig = num % 10;` [Sorry for the typo].