# How to make numbers in words in C

Tags: c, string

There is a code that I need to transform a number that the user types into a word, example : 123 = one, two, three. How can I continue this code?

```
int main()
{
    int number, count;
    char numberWritten[] = {"Zero" , "One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine"};

    printf("Type a number: ");
    scanf("%d" , &number);

    for (i = 0; i<=9; i++)
    {
        printf("")
    }

}
```

I´d like to add that i am a newbie, that I just started learning about strings and that I don´t know what void is or where to put it.

Comment: Hint: `numberWritten[2] == "Two"`

Comment: Hint+1: `#include <string.h> ---->strcmp`

Comment: Another hint: [Getting each individual digit from a whole integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118490/getting-each-individual-digit-from-a-whole-integer).

Comment: @SomerandomITboy what for is `strcmp` here? I do not see any use.

Comment: I'm voting that this needs more focus because it's unclear what you do or do not understand about the language.  Based on your comment about `void`, it seems like you'll be unfamiliar with most language features an answerer might use to craft a solution.  For now, I suggest you read tutorials, and experiment bravely with your code. Focus on finding things that you observe that are different from your current understanding.  For example, try changing `printf("")` to `printf(numberWritten[number])` and see what kind of user input will break it.

Comment: @Wyck Imagine a complete newbie with 2 months with only 2 times a week classes. That´s me. I am still going to learn pointers in a week, so i'm that newbie. I thank you for your time while trying to help me. The second answer helped me answer it easily. I was trying for a day now, so that's why I asked here haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration for `numberWritten` is slightly wrong - it *should* be

```
//   +---- Need unary * here
//   |
//   V
char *numberWritten[] = {"Zero" , "One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine"};
```

The `char` type represents a *single* character, not a string.  In C, a string is a sequence of character values including a zero-valued terminator, so you need an *array* of `char` to store a string:

```
char foo[] = "One"; // equivalent to char foo[] = {'O', 'n', 'e', 0};
                    // equivalent to char foo[4]; foo[0] = 'O'; foo[1] = 'n'; etc.
```

If you don't specify the number of elements in a declaration, the array size is taken from the number of elements in the initializer.  The string `"One"` is equivalent to the sequence `{'O', 'n', 'e', 0}`, which is 4 elements.

Since you want to store an array of *strings*, you either need to declare `numberWritten` as an array *of arrays* of `char`:

```
// The longest strings are 5 characters long, so each
// individual string needs an array of 6 characters to account
// for the string terminator
char numberWritten[][6] = { "One", "Two", ... };
```

**OR**

you need to declare an array of *pointers* to char:

```
char *numberWritten[] = { "One", "Two", ... };
```

Each string literal is itself an array expression, and in most circumstances array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions.  Since you probably don't want those strings to change, it would be safer to declare that as

```
const char *numberWritten[] = { "One", "Two", ... };
```

That way you can't accidentally update the contents of each `numberWritten[i]`.

As far as printing these out, you're very close.  Just remember the following:

- `numberWritten[0] == "Zero"`, `numberWritten[1] == "One"`, etc.  IOW, each `numberWritten[i]` (hint hint hint) corresponds to the word for the `i`'th value.

  To print a string value with `printf`, use the `%s` conversion specifier.  Example:

  ```
  char foo[] = "this is a string";
  printf( "%s\n", foo ); // writes "this is a string" followed by a newline to standard output
  ```

Comment: Thank you! My code now runs! I appreciate that you were able to explain it that simply! The printing part I knew was wrong, haha, but I really thank you! I tried both of your suggestions and both of them worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
void printnumber(unsigned number)
{
    static const char * const numberWritten[] = {"Zero" , "One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine"};
    if(number/10)
        printnumber(number / 10);
    printf("%s ", numberWritten[number % 10]);
}
```

or

```
void printnumber(int number)
{
    static const char * const numberWritten[] = {"Zero" , "One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine"};
    if(number/10)
       printnumber(number / 10);
    else
        if(number < 0 && number > -10) printf("minus ");
    printf("%s ", numberWritten[abs(number % 10)]);
}
```

or without recursion

```
void printnumber(int number)
{
    int mask = 1;
    static const char * const numberWritten[] = {"Zero" , "One" , "Two" , "Three" , "Four" , "Five" , "Six" , "Seven" , "Eight" , "Nine"};
    
    while(abs(number / mask) > 10) mask *= 10;
    if(number < 0) printf("minus ");
    for(; mask; mask /= 10)
        printf("%s ", numberWritten[abs(number / mask) % 10]);
}
```

Comment: I´m sorry, but could you explain it without using void? I´m fairly new to programming and I didn´t learn about void yet. Is it able to be done with a repetition structure or a switch? I´m sorry for bothering

Comment: Please verify your code before posting it as an answer. Both resursive functions will not print anything for input of `0`, The iterative one prints `Zero` for input `10` and `minus Four Two Nine Four Nine Six Seven Two Eight One ` for input `-11`.

Comment: @CiaPan good spot - but your instruction tone `Please verify your code before posting it as an answer` I'm finding as at least improper.

Comment: I apologize. I'm not fluent in English and I make lots of mistakes in casual talk, but never meaning to offend anybody.

Comment: I meant [our answers may be utilized by others](https://geek-and-poke.com/geekandpoke/2016/11/27/good-questions), so it's not good to mislead them.

Comment: @CiaPan so it was enough to point the problem, BTW it is good to delete comments which are not valid anymore. Does it work now OK?

Comment: The no-recursion version still produces `Zero` for input `10` and `minus Zero One Zero` for `-1010`.